# Segmentation Fault in C when writing to a file

Tags: c

```
void frameInfoData(int i,int j,int k)
{
    FILE *frameData;
    frameData=fopen("frame_Data.txt","a");
    fprintf(frameData,"Packet number is %d      Packet L %d         Packet Header L %d      ",i,j,k);
    fprintf(frameData,"\n");

}
```

Above is my code to write a file. My data is about 3170 lines long. When I run this program it gives me a segmentation fault and dumps core. But when I controlled the writing and write even 3169 lines it will write very easily and correctly.

I am new to C programming - please help me in this context.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check result of `fopen()`. Remember to `fclose()` if file successfully opened.

Comment: which machine you are on ?

Comment: i am working on windows 7 and using cygwin to compile

Answer (score 2):

add:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//other code here

if (frameData == NULL) {
  perror("fopen()");
  return;
}
```

This should get your debugging started...

Don't forget to `fclose(frameData)` before returning, that may also be causing an error (file already opened) in the second time the function is called.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely NOT a failure of `fopen()` but you should check it and exit the program if it's not working as following (it returns a NULL pointer when not working):

```
FILE* fp = fopen("SOMEFILE.txt", "a");
if(!fp) //in other words - NOT fp - means FP == NULL
{
  printf("Error: Could not open the file specified.\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

The logical reason would be you not using `fclose()`. `fopen()` always changes (I mean it returns a different pointer for different paths) and so it uses dynamic memory such as `malloc()` if you learned it which is a lot slower than static memory. The dynamic memory will
still be 'used' in the program (no matter if it's in a function or anywhere) until you supposedly 'free' it - when using `malloc()` you'd free the memory simply by using the function `free()`.
When using `fopen()` - the way to 'free' that dynamic memory is using `fclose()` on that pointer - this way:

```
fclose(FILE_POINTER_NAME);
```

when FILE_POINTER_NAME is the... hmm... well, the file pointer name.

Hope I helped.